# How to signal orphaned background process?

Tags: bash, unix, signals, tcl, orphan

I am executing a shell script in background from my tcl script. The tcl script ends execution after some time. At this point I assume the background shell script becomes orphan and is adopted by init.

```
set res [catch { exec sudo $script &}]
```

Now the problem is I am not able to signal my (orphaned) background script. But why? Ok it now belongs to init but why can't I signal it. Only sigkill seems to work and that kills it - I need to trigger the signal handler I've written to handle SIGUSR2

```
trap 'process' SIGUSR2
```

Why can't I signal my orphan background process? Is there no way this can be done? Or is there some workaround?

EDIT: Seems to work fine when the sleep is not involved. See sample code below:

```
trap 'kill `cat /var/run/sleep.pid`; foo' SIGUSR2;

foo(){ echo test; }

while true; do
  echo -n .
  sleep 100 &
  echo ${!} > /var/run/sleep.pid
  wait ${!}
done
```

Works fine when not orphaned - but in the case of orphan process I think the problem is the true pid of sleep gets overwritten and I'm not able to kill it when the trap arrives.

Answer (score 2):

lets run a small script like that:

```
bash -c '(trap foo SIGUSR2;foo(){ echo test; };while true; do echo -n .;sleep 1;done) & echo $!'; read
```

It will fork a background process which just runs and outputs some dots. It will also output the PID of the process, which you can use to check and signal it.

```
$ ps -f 19489
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY      STAT   TIME CMD
michas   19489     1  0 23:45 pts/8    S      0:00 bash -c (trap foo SIGUS...
```

Because the forking shell died directly after running the command in background, the process is now owned by init (PPID=1).

Now you can signal the process to call the handler:

```
kill -USR2 19489
```

If you do, you will notice the "test" output at the terminal printing the dots.

There should be no difference, whether you start a background process from shell or tcl. If it runs you can send it a signal and if there is a handler, it will be called.

If it really does not answer to signals it might be blocked, waiting for something. For example in a `sleep` or waiting for some IO.

Comment: It is waiting for a sleep to finish, but I'm writing the pid of the sleep to a file and on signal handler I'm reading this pid and killing it and then calling my function. 

Weird part is this works just fine when the background script is not orphaned.

Comment: @egorulz Tcl really doesn't interfere with signal handling of subprocesses; what michas writes is spot on. I think we need more details of the problem script to solve this mystery (e.g., you might've somehow got the script to do the waiting in a subprocess or set the signal handler in the wrong process).

Comment: This seems like a problem in your code. Try to minimize your code, leave out everything that is not absolutely necessary to reproduce your problem. Either you then spot the problem yourself or you end up with a small piece of code you should add to your question.

Comment: Yes, I did minimize the script. The issue was still happening - I then decided to directly signal the sleep instead of signalling my script which then on trapping the signal kills the sleep. 

That fixed the problem. But I'm left wondering why.